# 'Handler proccessing failed; nestedexception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject'

Tags: java, json

I am converting json string to JSONOBJECT  and i use import org.json.JSONObject
but i use this

`String jsonString = "{\"stat\": { \"sdr\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\", \"rcv\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\", \"time\": \"UTC in millis\", \"type\": 1, \"subt\": 1, \"argv\": [{\"type\": 1, \"val\":\"stackoverflow\"}]}}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);`

result: i get error

`'Handler proccessing failed; nestedexception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject'`

i have json-20170516.jar into spring-mvc project and i run this project in tomcat server.
i have onother project simple java project and using above code for this simple java project and thisworked correctly. i'm confusing for above problem.

Comment: i am using JSONObject onto spring-mvc project.

Answer (score -1):

NoClassDefFoundError occurs when your jars are missing. The json jar should either be provided explicitly or as a shared library in your server. Once the jar is added, your issue should be resolved.

---

Note: You should mention a lot more details like

- how are you running the code (as a standalone or on a server)
- if you are running on a server, which is the server, what is the java runtime
- also, format the code as

`String jsonString = ""; //all your code snippet`

Comment: thanks for answer, i use 'json-20170516.jar' into spring-mvc project and i run this project in tomcat server. but i get above error.